# C#: List add object initializer

Tags: c#, initialization

Lets say I have this class:

```
class MyList<T>
{

}
```

What must I do to that class, to make the following possible:

```
var list = new MyList<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have an Add method and implement IEnumerable.

```
class MyList<T> : IEnumerable
{
  public void Add(T t)
  {

  }

  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    //...
  }
}

public void T()
{
  MyList<int> a = new MyList<int>{1,2,3};
}
```

Comment: +1, you may want to add that it must take a parameter of the type in the collection.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. It would be weird, but your Add method does not need to take type T. It could be: 

      public void Add(string t, char c){}
and you could call

      MyList<int> a = new MyList<int>{{"A", 'c'}, {"B", 'd'}};

Answer (score 1):

Implementing ICollection on MyList will let the initalizer syntax work

```
class MyList<T> : ICollection<T>
{
}
```

Although the bare minimum would be:

```
public class myList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public void Add(T val)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ICollection<T> is also good.
```